# Message priorization in Marketing Coud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

Is there a feature in Marketing Cloud where I can prioritize one message over another if a subscriber receives several messages on the same day.

Then, I can choose to only send one email per day per recipient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No.

You basically have two options

1. The easy one: Use [Einstein Engagement Frequency](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.mc_anb_eef.htm&type=5) to monitor the saturation of your recipients, and see whether some of them are receiving more than the recommended number of emails. EEF will allow you to tap into this data, and suppress oversaturated recipients from sends.
2. The hard one: Use a combination of [SQL Query](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_use_the_sql_query_activity.htm&type=5) (to get all today's sends and store these into a single Data Extension) and an [exclusion script](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384149&type=1) to skip email sends for all contacts who already received an email today.

As you have already probably figured out, neither are optimal solutions, as they are only able to look "backwards" to see whether you have received emails in the past. It is not possible to see what is scheduled for a particular subscriber, and skip the earlier email on the morning of that day, so a more important sendout can happen in the afternoon.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :)